# Service cannot be stopped

Tags: java, android

In MainActicity I have a button. When clicking on it, a dialog will be opened. That dialog contains a button. When clicking on it, a service will be started and the same dialog will be closed. So far, everything works fine.

Now I want to stop that service. In MainActicity I press the same button to open the dialog again. I press the same button to stop the service but it doesn't stop.

The service is using a microphone. So when it gets started, on Windows 11 I see this icon on the taskbar:
[image]
So when the service gets stopped, this icon should be removed.

**MainActivity.java:**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Popup.ICustomTts, Popup.ITarget {
    private final Popup popupDialog = new Popup(R.layout.fragment_dialog);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button dialog = findViewById(R.id.dialog);
        dialog.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
            popupDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Speak");
        });
```

**Popup.java:**

I am trying to ensure that `mDialog` is not getting initialized several times. So this is how I tried it:

```java
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Popup extends DialogFragment {
    private Dialog mDialog;
    private boolean dialogIsActive = false;

    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "ResourceType"})
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view =  inflater.inflate(_layout, container, false);

        if (mDialog == null) {
            mDialog = new Dialog();
        }

        // Display fragment_dialog
        if (_layout == R.layout.fragment_dialog) {
            Button cta = view.findViewById(R.id.dialogCta);
            // Set the active button
            if (Helper.getSharedPreference(requireContext(), "dialog") != null && Helper.getSharedPreference(requireContext(), "dialog").equals("1")) {
                cta.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.button_red));
                cta.setText(R.string.dialog_do_not_listen);
                cta.setTextSize(17);
                dialogIsActive = true;
            }
           
            // Toggle the listener
            cta.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                if (!dialogIsActive) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (mDialog.hasRecordPermission(getContext())) {
                           mDialog.startService(getContext());
                            cta.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.button_red));
                            cta.setText(R.string.dialog_do_not_listen);
                            cta.setTextSize(17);
                            Helper.saveAsSharedPreference(requireContext(), "dialog", "1");
                            dialogIsActive = true;
                            requireContext().startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        mDialog.stopTheService(getContext());
                        cta.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.button_yellow));
                        cta.setText(R.string.dialog_listen);
                        Helper.removeSharedPreference(requireContext(), "dialog");
                        dialogIsActive = false;
                        requireContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**Dialog.java:**

```java
public class Dialog extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Intent getmServiceIntent() {
        return mServiceIntent;
    }
    private Intent mServiceIntent = null;

    public void startService(Context context) {
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(context, PicovoiceService.class);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("keywordFileName", "K_de_android_v2_0_0.ppn");
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("contextFileName", "K_de_android_v2_0_0.rhn");
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, mServiceIntent);
    }

    public void stopTheService(Context context) {
        if (mServiceIntent != null) {
            context.stopService(mServiceIntent);
        }
    }
```

When I debug my code, I see that `mDialog.stopTheService(getContext());` will be invoked and I don't get any errors. My suggestion is that the method is getting invoked based on the wrong instance, even if I tried to have 1 instance only.

So what is wrong with my code?

Comment: "but it doesn't stop" -- how are you determining this? Your [mcve] does not show the service.

Comment: @CommonsWare please read my question again. I have updated it.

Comment: "So when it gets started, on Windows 11 I see this icon on the taskbar: enter image description here So when the service gets stopped, this icon should be removed." -- that may or may not be true, depending on how Windows 11 did their Android integration. Beyond that, presumably you are doing something in your service that involves the microphone. Perhaps you are not cleaning that up in `onDestroy()` of your service. Again, your [mcve] does not show the service, so it will be difficult for anyone to help you with that service.

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't write that service. It is from a library. See https://github.com/Picovoice/picovoice/blob/master/demo/android/Service/picovoice-service-demo-app/src/main/java/ai/picovoice/picovoicedemoservice/PicovoiceService.java

Comment: "I didn't write that service" -- then perhaps that service has a bug. It is a demo, one that perhaps is not designed for your scenario. Or, perhaps that service (and the SDK that it uses) is not designed to work on Windows 11. Or, perhaps Windows 11 handles status bar icons differently than you expect. You might consider contacting the firm that published that demo for assistance in using their SDK in an Android app on Windows 11.

Comment: Regardless, if your `stopService()` call is happening, and your code is not crashing, then you are stopping the service. Services are natural singletons -- it is not possible to have more than one copy of the running service. Your issue is that your icon is not going away. The developers of that service might be able to assist you in determining why that icon is showing up and why it might not be going away.

Comment: @CommonsWare it is not about the icon only. The issue is that the microphone is still activated and voices can be recorded. When I stop the app on Android Studio, the icon will be removed. I have tested the demo from this library and the demo works fine.

Comment: When you stop the app in Android Studio, your process is being terminated. That is not the same as a service being stopped. Again: the developers of that service might be able to assist you further.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have figured out that it is because of `requireContext().startActivity(intent)`. If I remove that, it works fine. I have added this because I want the view of MainActivity to be changed.